# Apache Iceberg bug MERGE INTO PySpark with UDF causes: `Cannot generate code for expression`

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, apache-iceberg

I have encountered a major bug with `MERGE INTO` in Spark when writing into Apache Iceberg format using a python UDF. The problem is that when the column that is used in the `ON` clause of `MERGE INTO` has been affected by a UDF, the merge throws an error:

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:  org.apache.spark.SparkUnsupportedOperationException: Cannot generate code for expression: ...

I have created an example to showcase the issue:

```
import os

import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
import pyspark.sql.types as tp
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

deps = [
    "org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.3_2.12:1.2.1",
    "org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-aws:1.2.1",
    "software.amazon.awssdk:bundle:2.17.257",
    "software.amazon.awssdk:url-connection-client:2.17.257",
]
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = f"--packages {','.join(deps)} pyspark-shell"
os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = "minioadmin"
os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = "minioadmin"
os.environ["AWS_REGION"] = "eu-east-1"

catalog = "hive"
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.appName("Iceberg Reader")
    .config(
        "spark.sql.extensions",
        "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions",
    )
    .config(f"spark.sql.catalog.{catalog}", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog")
    .config(f"spark.sql.catalog.{catalog}.type", "hive")
    .config(f"spark.sql.catalog.{catalog}.uri", "thrift://localhost:9083")
    .config(
        f"spark.sql.catalog.{catalog}.io-impl", "org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO"
    )
    .config(f"spark.sql.catalog.{catalog}.s3.endpoint", "http://localhost:9000")
    .config(f"spark.sql.catalog.{catalog}.warehouse", "s3a://lakehouse")
    .config("spark.sql.defaultCatalog", catalog)
    .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()
)


@fn.udf(returnType=tp.IntegerType())
def return_self(inpt):
    return inpt


namespace = "ns"
table = "tab1"

# Create namespaces and table
spark.sql(f"CREATE NAMESPACE IF NOT EXISTS {namespace};")
spark.sql(f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {namespace}.{table} (col1 INT, col2 INT);")

# Create some data
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)],
    schema=tp.StructType(
        [
            tp.StructField("col1", tp.IntegerType()),
            tp.StructField("col2", tp.IntegerType()),
        ]
    ),
)

# This does work, because col1 is NOT affected!
df = df.withColumn("col2", return_self("col1"))
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")
spark.sql(
    f"""
MERGE INTO {namespace}.{table} A USING (SELECT * FROM tmp) B
ON A.col1 = B.col1
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET A.col1 = B.col1, A.col2 = B.col2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
"""
)

# This does NOT work!
df = df.withColumn("col1", return_self("col1"))
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")
spark.sql(
    f"""
MERGE INTO {namespace}.{table} A USING (SELECT * FROM tmp) B
ON A.col1 = B.col1
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET A.col1 = B.col1, A.col2 = B.col2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
"""
)
```

1. I created a very simple UDF that does not do any transformations and just returns the same data as the input.
2. When we transform `col2`, and perform `MERGE INTO` on `col1`, nothing happens and the data will be inserted normally.
3. When we "transform" `col1`, by passing it through the UDF, the `MERGE INTO` fails with the error:

> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.spark.SparkUnsupportedOperationException: Cannot generate code for expression: return_self(input[0, int, true])

Somehow it cannot deal with these UDFs.

Persisting the data, breaking the computation chain is a workaround:

```
# This is a workaround
df = df.withColumn("col1", return_self("col1"))
df.cache()
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")
spark.sql(
    f"""
MERGE INTO {namespace}.{table} A USING (SELECT * FROM tmp) B
ON A.col1 = B.col1
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET A.col1 = B.col1, A.col2 = B.col2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
"""
)
```

The workaround is annoying though. Especially for very large data. Probably you need to write the data somewhere then.

Does someone have a better idea of what is going on here?

Comment: Another possible workaround for large data that cannot be cached is checkpointing btw.